# Send to paypal data entered in the form by the user

Tags: jquery

I have not found what I was looking for and I have opened a new topic. I am integrating an e-commerce system into my site and it seems that everything works perfectly!
I just want to understand how I can forward to PayPal the information entered in the site form by the user such as name / surname, address, etc. !! I have entered all the possible variables in the PayPal checkout form but when the data is submitted on the PayPal site everything is shown (article, quantity, total etc.) except the data entered by the user. The user address already registered on Paypal is displayed but not the data entered on my site. I read that you have to enter variables and I put in the possible to test but it doesn't work.
I hope you can help me.

```
<form id="paypal-form" action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_ext-enter" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="business@example.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="address1" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="address2" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="city" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="state" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="zip" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="day_phone_a" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.example.com/shop.html" />
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.example.com/shop.html" />
<input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="cs" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
<input type="hidden" name="Ic" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="my site" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.example.com/shop.html">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
<input type="submit" id="paypal-btn" class="btn" value="Pay with PayPal" />
</form>
```

Jquery code

```
    // Add the required hidden values to the PayPal form before submitting

    populatePayPalForm: function() {
        var self = this;
        if( self.$paypalForm.length ) {
            var $form = self.$paypalForm;
            var cart = self._toJSONObject( self.storage.getItem( self.cartName ) );
            var shipping = self.storage.getItem( self.shippingRates );
            var numShipping = self._convertString( shipping );
            var cartItems = cart.items; 
            var singShipping = Math.floor( numShipping / cartItems.length );

            $form.attr( "action", self.paypalURL );
            $form.find( "input[name='business']" ).val( self.paypalBusinessEmail );
            $form.find( "input[name='currency_code']" ).val( self.paypalCurrency );

            for( var i = 0; i < cartItems.length; ++i ) {
                var cartItem = cartItems[i];
                var n = i + 1;
                var name = cartItem.product;
                var price = cartItem.price;
                var qty = cartItem.qty;

                $( "<div/>" ).html( "<input type='hidden' name='quantity_" + n + "' value='" + qty + "'/>" ).
                insertBefore( "#paypal-btn" );
                $( "<div/>" ).html( "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_" + n + "' value='" + name + "'/>" ).
                insertBefore( "#paypal-btn" );
                $( "<div/>" ).html( "<input type='hidden' name='item_number_" + n + "' value='Art. " + name + "'/>" ).
                insertBefore( "#paypal-btn" );
                $( "<div/>" ).html( "<input type='hidden' name='amount_" + n + "' value='" + self._formatNumber( price, 2 ) + "'/>" ).
                insertBefore( "#paypal-btn" );
                $( "<div/>" ).html( "<input type='hidden' name='shipping_" + n + "' value='" + self._formatNumber( singShipping, 2 ) + "'/>" ).
                insertBefore( "#paypal-btn" );

            }



        }
    },



    // Displays user information

    displayUserDetails: function() {
        if( this.$userDetails.length ) {
            if( this.storage.getItem( "shipping-name" ) == null ) {
                var name = this.storage.getItem( "billing-name" );
                var email = this.storage.getItem( "billing-email" );
                var phone = this.storage.getItem( "billing-phone" );
                var city = this.storage.getItem( "billing-city" );
                var province = this.storage.getItem( "billing-province" );
                var address = this.storage.getItem( "billing-address" );
                var zip = this.storage.getItem( "billing-zip" );
                var country = this.storage.getItem( "billing-country" );

                var html = "<div class='detail'>";
                    html += "<h2>Fatturazione e spedizione</h2>";
                    html += "<ul>";
                    html += "<li>" + name + "</li>";
                    html += "<li>" + email + "</li>";
                    html += "<li>" + phone + "</li>";
                    html += "<li>" + city + "</li>";
                    html += "<li>" + province + "</li>";
                    html += "<li>" + address + "</li>";
                    html += "<li>" + zip + "</li>";
                    html += "<li>" + country + "</li>";
                    html += "</ul></div>";

                this.$userDetails[0].innerHTML = html;
            } else {
                var name = this.storage.getItem( "billing-name" );
                var email = this.storage.getItem( "billing-email" );
                var phone = this.storage.getItem( "billing-phone" );
                var city = this.storage.getItem( "billing-city" );
                var province = this.storage.getItem( "billing-province" );
                var address = this.storage.getItem( "billing-address" );
                var zip = this.storage.getItem( "billing-zip" );
                var country = this.storage.getItem( "billing-country" );

                var sName = this.storage.getItem( "shipping-name" );
                var sCity = this.storage.getItem( "shipping-city" );
                var sProvince = this.storage.getItem( "shipping-province" );
                var sAddress = this.storage.getItem( "shipping-address" );
                var sZip = this.storage.getItem( "shipping-zip" );
                var sCountry = this.storage.getItem( "shipping-country" );

                var html = "<div class='detail'>";
                    html += "<h2>Fatturazione</h2>";
                    html += "<ul>";
                    html += "<li>" + name + "</li>";
                    html += "<li>" + email + "</li>";
                    html += "<li>" + phone + "</li>";
                    html += "<li>" + city + "</li>";
                    html += "<li>" + province + "</li>";
                    html += "<li>" + address + "</li>";
                    html += "<li>" + zip + "</li>";
                    html += "<li>" + country + "</li>";
                    html += "</ul></div>";

                    html += "<div class='detail right'>";
                    html += "<h2>Spedizione</h2>";
                    html += "<ul>";
                    html += "<li>" + sName + "</li>";
                    html += "<li>" + sCity + "</li>";
                    html += "<li>" + sProvince + "</li>";
                    html += "<li>" + sAddress + "</li>";
                    html += "<li>" + sZip + "</li>";
                    html += "<li>" + sCountry + "</li>";
                    html += "</ul></div>";

                this.$userDetails[0].innerHTML = html;    

            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: *"but it doesn't work"* needs more clarity.

Comment: What results are you getting, what errors do you see.

Comment: Hello, in practice when the data from the paypal form is sent, the product, shipping and subtotal costs are displayed in the summary on the paypal page but the data entered by the user in the form such as name, surname and address are not displayed! I entered several variables in the paypal form but they are not displayed.